# How to replace a document matched by _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Working on an API I want to do a full document update of a MongoDB object.

This is my current code that works but it feels wrong to have to delete the _id every time. Is there a better way to do this?

```
        PutDoco : function(doco){
            return new Promise(function(Resolve,Reject){
                delete doco._id;
                db.collection('docos').updateOne(
                    {"details.ID":doco.details.ID},
                    doco,
                    function(err,result){
                        if(err)
                            return Reject(err);

                        Resolve(result);
                    }
                );
            });
        },
```

Comment: Does `doco._id` always match the `_id` of the document you're updating? If not, it should feel right to remove it, as it wouldn't make sense otherwise as `_id` values are immutable. :)

Comment: It always matches it. (I get the document from from Mongo and want to just dump the document back in Mongo )

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replaceOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#replaceOne) instead when replacing all contents of a document (besides `_id` which is immutable). And because `replaceOne` returns a promise if you don't pass it a callback, you can reduce your whole function down to:

```
return db.collection('docos').replaceOne({"details.ID":doco.details.ID}, doco);
```

However, it might be clearer (and faster) to find the document to replace using `_id` instead:

```
return db.collection('docos').replaceOne({_id: doco._id}, doco);
```